# How to access "All apps" fast on Windows 10 Full screen start

Tags: windows-10, start-screen

This is the start when "Use Start full scren" is on. The *Pinned tiles* are the default. How can I display the *All apps* list real fast without using a mouse?

[image]

This is the desired view, best opened instantly using some fancy hidden key-shortcut.
[image]

**Windows 10 v1703 - Creators update, build 15063.296*

Comment: type this in Run `explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>tab</kbd> (if you have a tile already selected on the right, press it twice), then press <kbd>down arrow</kbd> twice, followed by <kbd>enter</kbd> or <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>.

Alternatively, even quicker, start typing the first letters of the program you want to launch.

And don't forget, you can pin programs from the all apps to your startmenu, which creates tiles. You can drag several tiles ontop of eachother to create a group (like a folder) so you can basically create a folder for all your apps.

That being said, there is **no** real instant jump into that specific view using any secret hotkey, so if you don't want this and want an even quicker way, consider disabling the Full Screen Start menu, and after pressing start, drag the startmenu edges to the top and the right to make it as big as possible.

Comment: Cool, I haven't realised that you can drag the edges to enlarge it.

Comment: @Qwerty Yeah. Does this resolve your issue? If so, please mark this answer as answered, so others know you no longer need any help.

Comment: No, it doesn't actually. I have updated the question to better express what is desired.

Comment: So, my solution does work, the first part. Its just not an instant thing which unfortunately is not possible unless you go for an alternate startmenu, such as Classic Shell.

Comment: There are dozens of tab/window/screen switchers using different key kombinations, I was hoping there will be some undocumented for the specific view in question as well. I don't find navigating in context menus or other elements as an acceptable solution. I will rather turn off the full screen start than navigating in it. Edited and accepted.

Comment: Accepted the edit. :)